# SQL Server Collate Not returning field as expected- Polish Characters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssms, collation

I know there are a million questions about this but nothing I have found seems to work for me. Database holds many names, just started adding contacts in Poland.

Front End (Web) shows: Ondřej

Back End (SSMS) shows: Ond?ej

It's not showing the ř in SSMS, but it obviously is storing it because it is showing correctly on the front end. I'm trying to make an SSRS report and all my reports show Ond?ej and I need to show either Ondřej or Ondrej.

When I run the following in SSMS, the result is different depending on if it a text strong or a database field:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, 'Ondřej'
 FROM TABLENAME
 COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI
```

I get Ond?ej for FIRSTNAME and Ondrej for the hard coded version.

What is the difference between pulling from the field and the string? I don't know what datatype 'Ondřej' is converted to when just typed into the query. Is there any way to pull this data in a query that can be used in SSR?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: It's nvarchar(50)

Comment: It just cannot be. SSMS is unicode application and it cannot show unicode symbol incorrect. Maybe you use another table

Comment: Reguarding your code.It's not syntactically correct and just cannot be executed. Besides, Cyrillic has nothing to do with Polish characters. What you have instead you are passing a Unicode string without specifying N in the context of database that has the collation other than Polish, you should pass it as Unicode like this: select N'Ondřej'

Comment: >>>I don't know what datatype 'Ondřej' is converted to when just typed into the query<<< When you enter your query containing unicode without passing it as unicode (without specifying N) in a context of database with collation different than Polish, the convertion is made. It replaces the ř symbol with the "nearest" to it found in CP corresponding to database collation, so it's replaced by "r".

Comment: sepupic, it does run. I'm not saying it is good- I got it from one of the websites I found- but it does run as stated above.

Comment: What does run, your code? It just has no sense, I mean using Collate *after the table*. It does make sense after a string field like this: select firstname COLLATE  Cyrillic_General_CI_AI from tablename, otherwise it gives you an error. In any case, have you ever seen cyrillic characters? It's an alphabet on its own, has nothing to do with Polish that uses Latin characters with some diacritical marks